# How to filter data based on count without hitting the sub-table/sub-query twice?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, hiveql

I am having following data, which I want to filter out by applying counts on cd column (i.e. get all columns such that count(cd) > 3)

Data sample (derived by sub-query)

```
cd  c1  c2  d1
----------------
aa  23  681 4850
aa  23  942 4850
aa  28  944 4881
aa  28  221 4850
bb  46  443 9082
cc  77  171 2831
cc  77  272 2831
dd  18  798 5993
xx  71  166 8755
xx  71  482 3818
xx  71  565 7598
xx  71  603 7246
xx  71  649 4293
xx  71  681 7321
xx  71  250 7453
xx  22  276 3818
xx  22  107 8755
yy  28  143 5802
zz  33  624 3205
zz  33  767 1532
zz  33  372 3205
zz  33  679 3838
```

I am using following query, but I do not want to hit test_data as data volume is large in hive table. (note: here test_data is being derived from other sub-queries in the same Query)

```
SELECT cd, c1, c2, d1 
FROM test_data
WHERE cd IN (SELECT cd FROM test_data group by cd having count(cd) > 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the window function to get a count for each `cd` group but not actually aggregate and then filter out rows where the count is lower than 4. Although this still required a sub query you are not joining any table so it should be somewhat more performant.

```
SELECT 
cd, 
c1, 
c2, 
d1 
FROM (
  SELECT
  cd, 
  c1, 
  c2, 
  d1,
  count(1) OVER (PARTITION BY cd ORDER BY c1 DESC) as cd_count 
  FROM test_data
) test_data_1
WHERE cd_count > 3;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I want cd_count > 3, which will miss first two records

Answer (score 0):

use windowing functions to get the count of cd and then filter data using where clause as in below query

select  * from (Select cd,c1,c2,d1 , count(cd)   OVER (PARTITION BY cd ) as  cnt  FROM test_data) a  where cnt> 3